# How to fire event on horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling, detect

I have a div inside my page which is horizontally scrollable. I am making a scroll indicator for this element in Javascript.

When I try `document.getElementsByClassName('flickity-viewport')[0].onscroll` instead of `window.onscroll` it doesn't work at all :( (in console, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onscroll' of undefined`)

Also tried `.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction)` but it doesn't work and send a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined` in console.

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
          var winScroll = document.getElementsByClassName('flickity-viewport')[0].scrollLeft || document.getElementsByClassName('flickity-viewport')[0].scrollLeft;
          var height = document.getElementsByClassName('flickity-viewport')[0].scrollWidth - document.getElementsByClassName('flickity-viewport')[0].clientWidth;
          var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
          document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = + scrolled + "%";
}
```

No errors in console due to that script.
Everything works except it only updates the scroll indicator when I scroll vertically the page, whereas I'd like it to update each time I scroll horizontally my div.

Does anyone have a solution ? :)

Thanks !

Comment: Hi anyone can help please ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The console error is telling you that the element you are trying to attach the listener function to is `undefined`.

The error is similar no matter if you use `elem.onscroll` or `elem.addEventListener` because in both cases the problem is with the element selector.

Just enter `document.getElementsByClassName('flickity-viewport')[0]` into your developer console and make sure that the element actually exists (and doesn't return `undefined`).

Than you can modify your function like this:

```
function myFunction( event ) {
    var winScroll = event.target.scrollLeft;
    var height = event.target.scrollWidth - event.target.clientWidth;
    var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = + scrolled + "%";
}
```

It now uses `event.target` instead of repeating the `getElementsByClassName`. The event is automatically passed by the `scroll` listener to the callback function `myFunction`.

Now just attach the function any way you like:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('flickity-viewport')[0]; // Make sure this doesn't return undefined

elem.onscroll = myFunction;

// or

elem.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction );
```